# Pyspark Exploding Column on Boolean Conditional

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling with exploding on a conditional in Pyspark.

I have two tables:

`joined_data`:

| poi_code | cleaned_home_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"12": 4, "34":2, "56":8}] |
| 2 | [{"12": 8, "56": 10, "78":4}] |
| 3 | [{"34": 1}] |

and `nyc_code`:

| code | zipcode |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 11221 |
| 56 | 11385 |
| 78 | 10471 |

I would like to explode `joined_data` on `home_code` but only for values that exist in `nyc_code`.

Desired result:

| poi_code | cleaned_home_code | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"12": 4, "34":2, "56":8}] | 12 |
| 1 | [{"12": 4, "34":2, "56":8}] | 56 |
| 2 | [{"12": 8, "56": 10, "78":4}] | 12 |
| 2 | [{"12": 8, "56": 10, "78":4}] | 56 |
| 2 | [{"12": 8, "56": 10, "78":4}] | 78 |

Can anyone please advise? I have tried exploding and then filtering out non-nyc codes, the challenge is that my dataset becomes too large to compute in the desired timeframe. This is why I'm wondering if I can apply the filtering condition as I explode, so that I only explode values that meet the desired criteria. I am a spark novice so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `cleaned_home_code` is `ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))` right?

Comment: what is the data type of `cleaned_home_code`?

Comment: What is the number of records in `nyc_code` (number of distinct code) ?

Comment: cleaned_home_code is MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()) and the number of records in nyc_code is ~6k

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Importing necessary packages

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, map_keys
```

1. Explode the `cleaned_home_code` columns and extract key out of it

```
joined_data = joined_data.withColumn("exp_cleaned_home_code", explode("cleaned_home_code"))
joined_data = joined_data.withColumn("home_code_key", map_keys("exp_cleaned_home_code"))
joined_data = joined_data.withColumn("home_code_key", explode("home_code_key"))
```

2. perform an inner join with the `nyc_code` DataFrame

```
joined_nyc = joined_data \
    .join(nyc_code, joined_data.home_code_key == nyc_code.code) \
    .orderBy("poi_code") \
    .drop("home_code_key", "zipcode", "exp_cleaned_home_code")

joined_nyc.show(truncate=False)
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+------------------------------+----+
|poi_code|cleaned_home_code             |code|
+--------+------------------------------+----+
|1       |[{56 -> 8, 34 -> 2, 12 -> 4}] |12  |
|1       |[{56 -> 8, 34 -> 2, 12 -> 4}] |56  |
|2       |[{78 -> 4, 56 -> 10, 12 -> 8}]|12  |
|2       |[{78 -> 4, 56 -> 10, 12 -> 8}]|56  |
|2       |[{78 -> 4, 56 -> 10, 12 -> 8}]|78  |
+--------+------------------------------+----+
```

Comment: thanks! ideally thought i want to apply the conditional as i explode the column, so that i only explode values that fall within nyc_code. this is because of time constaints, where exploding the dataframe takes much longer than desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3.1, You can filter your `cleaned_home_code` column, keeping only values in a specified list before exploding it.

However, this specified list can't be a dataframe so you first need to transform your `nyc_code` to a python list. In your case, as your `nyc_code` dataframe is rather small (~6000 records), you can collect it and pass it to the [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html?highlight=filter#pyspark.sql.functions.filter) function to remove all values not in `nyc_code`. Then, you can explode filtered column, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# create list of codes you want to keep
kept_codes = [r[0] for r in nyc_code.select(F.col('code').cast('string')).distinct().collect()]

# explode on filtered map
result = joined_data.withColumn(
  'code',
  F.explode(
    F.filter(
      F.map_keys(F.col('cleaned_home_code')), 
      lambda c: c.isin(kept_codes)
    )
  )
)
```

You then get the following `result` dataframe:

```
+--------+----------------------------+----+
|poi_code|cleaned_home_code           |code|
+--------+----------------------------+----+
|1       |{56 -> 8, 34 -> 2, 12 -> 4} |56  |
|1       |{56 -> 8, 34 -> 2, 12 -> 4} |12  |
|2       |{78 -> 4, 56 -> 10, 12 -> 8}|78  |
|2       |{78 -> 4, 56 -> 10, 12 -> 8}|56  |
|2       |{78 -> 4, 56 -> 10, 12 -> 8}|12  |
+--------+----------------------------+----+
``
```